# Parse JSON from API response with double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, json

Ugh. So noobish, but I can't seem to parse this string into valid JSON within Javascript. How should I? This data is coming from a Foursquare checkin.

**EDIT: Here is an image of what I'm trying to get at, the "checkin" property**
[image]

```
"{"id":"52e2ac6511d28d5cd63ee41f","createdAt":1390586981,"type":"checkin","shout":"Vd","timeZone":"America\/Denver","timeZoneOffset":-420,"user":{"id":"76097213","firstName":"SpencerTesting","lastName":"GardnerTesting","gender":"none","relationship":"self","photo":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/img\/blank_boy.png","tips":{"count":0},"lists":{"groups":[{"type":"created","count":1,"items":[]}]},"homeCity":"Pleasant Grove, UT","bio":"","contact":{"email":"email@email.com"}},"venue":{"id":"4b83ec97f964a520d81631e3","name":"Joseph Smith Building","contact":{},"location":{"address":"770 E University Pkwy","crossStreet":"at BYU","lat":40.245901424248,"lng":-111.65174603462219,"postalCode":"84604","cc":"US","city":"Provo","state":"UT","country":"United States"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d198941735","name":"College Academic Building","pluralName":"College Academic Buildings","shortName":"Academic Building","icon":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories\/education\/default.png","parents":["College & University"],"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":1695,"usersCount":281,"tipCount":1},"likes":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"beenHere":{"count":0}}}"
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that in the first place.  What are you trying to write?

Comment: are you sure that's the string, or did you copy that from chrome's console? if it really is like that, just JSON.parse(str.slice(1,-1))

Comment: as i suspected, it is a valid string, the wrapping quotes are cosmetic in chrome so you can spot JSON vs a deep object... if you alert() the string you won't see the quotes...

Comment: Edited to show more information about where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes around the string rather than double quotes:

```
JSON.parse('{"id":"52e2ac6511d28d5cd63ee41f","createdAt":1390586981,"type":"checkin","shout":"Vd","timeZone":"America\/Denver","timeZoneOffset":-420,"user":{"id":"76097213","firstName":"SpencerTesting","lastName":"GardnerTesting","gender":"none","relationship":"self","photo":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/img\/blank_boy.png","tips":{"count":0},"lists":{"groups":[{"type":"created","count":1,"items":[]}]},"homeCity":"Pleasant Grove, UT","bio":"","contact":{"email":"email@email.com"}},"venue":{"id":"4b83ec97f964a520d81631e3","name":"Joseph Smith Building","contact":{},"location":{"address":"770 E University Pkwy","crossStreet":"at BYU","lat":40.245901424248,"lng":-111.65174603462219,"postalCode":"84604","cc":"US","city":"Provo","state":"UT","country":"United States"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d198941735","name":"College Academic Building","pluralName":"College Academic Buildings","shortName":"Academic Building","icon":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories\/education\/default.png","parents":["College & University"],"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":1695,"usersCount":281,"tipCount":1},"likes":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"beenHere":{"count":0}}}')
```

works for me.

In the case that the string is dynamically generated and actually contains the `"` character, follow dandavis's suggestion of removing the `"` using `JSON.parse(str.slice(1,-1))` where `str` contains the JSON response to your Foursquare API call.

However, this shouldn't be necessary since the surrounding quotes are a side effect of printing to the console. In reality, the value of the `checkin` key is perfectly valid JSON that can be parsed regularly with `JSON.parse`. However, if copied off the console, the extra `"` need to be replaced since all the inner `"` aren't displayed as escaped in the console.

**If** you're using a jQuery and not vanilla JS to send your AJAX queries, specifying `dataType: 'json'` during the query will automatically result in parsed data passed to the `success` callback. I believe this is the default behavior for `$.ajax()` if the response type is `application/json` or equivalent.

Comment: and what if the data one day contains an apos ?

Comment: I assumed this was some static data he wanted to parse since the data's origin wasn't specified.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to parse this string into valid JSON within Javascript

You don't parse a string *into* JSON. The string **contains** JSON, and you parse it to convert the JSON in JavaScript arrays and objects.

In your case, you are looking for

```
 var data = JSON.parse(obj.checkin);
```

because the value of the `checking` property is a string containing JSON. Then you can [access the properties of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).